# cannot start sonatype nexus 2.14.2-02

Tags: java

After upgrading sonatype nexus to 2.14.2-02 from 2.7.2, nexus will not start. The log file indicates the following error:

> WARN  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED
>   com.yammer.metrics.jetty.InstrumentedHandler@3571ef12:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.sonatype.nexus.util.file.DirSupport.mkdir(Ljava/io/File;)V

Here is the wrapper.log file:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
jvm 1    | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
jvm 1    | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
jvm 1    | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
jvm 1    | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,411-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher - Starting with arguments: [./conf/jetty.xml, ./conf/jetty-requestlog.xml]
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,414-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher - JVM ID: 1, JVM PID: 2462, Wrapper PID: 2460, User: nexus
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,449-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder - Properties:
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   application-conf='/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/../sonatype-work/nexus/conf'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   application-host='0.0.0.0'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   application-port='8081'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   bundleBasedir='/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   java.awt.headless='true'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   networkaddress.cache.ttl='3600'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-app='/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/nexus/WEB-INF'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-webapp='/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/nexus'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-webapp-context-path='/nexus'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   nexus-work='/usr/local/sonatype-work/nexus'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout='30000'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   runtime='/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/nexus/WEB-INF'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   security-xml-file='/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/../sonatype-work/nexus/conf/security.xml'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,450-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   storage.diskCache.bufferSize='4096'
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,451-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - Java: 1.7.0_40, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Oracle Corporation, 24.0-b56
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,451-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - OS: Linux, 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64, amd64
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,451-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - User: nexus, en, /home/nexus
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,451-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - CWD: /usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,462-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher - TMP: /usr/local/sonatype-work/nexus/tmp
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,464-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Starting
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,472-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/conf/jetty.xml
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,663-0500 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Applying configuration: file:/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/conf/jetty-requestlog.xml
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,677-0500 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Starting: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@3b7eb6b2
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:16,679-0500 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-8.1.16.v20140903
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:17,771-0500 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap - Initializing
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:17,772-0500 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap - Using bootstrap launcher configuration
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:17,777-0500 WARN  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/nexus,file:/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/nexus/},/usr/local/nexus-2.14.2-01/nexus: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonatype.nexus.util.file.DirSupport.mkdir(Ljava/io/File;)V
jvm 1    | java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonatype.nexus.util.file.DirSupport.mkdir(Ljava/io/File;)V
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:115) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247) [nexus-bootstrap-2.14.2-01.jar:2.14.2-01]
jvm 1    | 2017-01-24 16:05:17,778-0500 WARN  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED com.yammer.metrics.jetty.InstrumentedHandler@3571ef12: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonatype.nexus.util.file.DirSupport.mkdir(Ljava/io/File;)V
jvm 1    | java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonatype.nexus.util.file.DirSupport.mkdir(Ljava/io/File;)V
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:115) ~[na:na]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247) [nexus-bootstrap-2.14.2-01.jar:2.14.2-01]
```

Comment: did you disable/remove/update plugins before updating?  3rd party plugins might need update.  From 2.x to 2.14 should be drop in replacment, but you never now https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464338-Sonatype-Nexus-Upgrade-and-Compatibility-Notes

Comment: Thank you! the problem where the plugins.

Comment: I should have made it an answer, so I did now

Answer (score 0):

did you disable/remove/update plugins before updating? 3rd party plugins might need updating